# Ajax Call Thinks That Data Contains [ ]'s when it should be empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code which gets all posts. it works but when there are no posts it still sends [] as data, so there will never be any errors even if the data is empty.

Result is always ["Hello"]as an example, but the []s' aren't specified anywhere.. don't know why they are there.

the ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btnGetPosts').click(function() {

            var recieverID = $('#RecieverID').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Posts/GetPosts" ,
                data:{username:recieverID},
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",

                 // it always skips error since it thinks that data contains [].
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                   alert("Error, please contact the website administrator");


                },
                 // when there is data it always shows the data like so: ["Hello"]
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#userPosts").append(data).html();

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this is my web-api controller

```
public List<string> GetPosts(int userID)
    {


        //// uses linq to get a specific user post (all posts)
        var userPost = PostRepository.GetSpecificUserPosts(userID);

            return userPost;
        }

    }
```

and below is my Repository code that gets all the posts from the database.

```
 public List<string> GetSpecificUserPosts(int user)
    {
        using (var context = new DejtingEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Posts
                .Where(x => x.RecieverID == user)
                .Select(x => x.Body)
                .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the result of `ToList()`, which is always a `new List()`; it is never null. This then gets serlialised to a string by your `GetPosts` action and returned to your JS code as `[]`.

Even if you returned null from the action, the `error` handler in your AJAX code would not be hit as a 200 status code would be returned. `error` only fires if something *other* than 200 is returned.

You can either check for the number of results in your `GetSpecificUserPosts` and manually return `null` if there are none, or alternatively you can check `data.length` in the `success` handler of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Hmm.. you have any idea how I could solve this riddle?

Comment: or you could return 204 server error to fire ajax error handler >>im not an asp guy ;)

Comment: ^ Or that, `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)`.

Comment: ↑↑↑ wouldn't it be better then `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)`?

Comment: Yeah, I was just giving the example of creating the error response. Any status code required can be returned. I couldn't remember what a 204 was :)

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax error handler only fires if an error occurs during a request such as a 500 error.  You should probably just take into account an empty list in your success handler such as:

```
success: function(data) {
   if(data.length) {  // if the array has elements then append them
       $('#userPosts').append(data);
   } else {  // If no elements show the alert.
        alert("Error, please contact the website administrator");  
   }
}
```